# What should I call a highly restricted username field?

Tags: registration, username

I am designing an account creation form that will prompt for username and pass phrase. The username will represent the user for login and communication with other users. It will also be used across multiple protocols (e.g. email prefix), including ones not yet planned for, so I need to severely restrict input to values that will be compatible with multiple protocols (e.g. no periods). The restrictions are as follows:

- must begin a-z
- can be followed by a sequence of characters from a-z and/or 0-9
- must be lowercase
- nothing else is permitted (uppercase, punctuation, unicode...)

So a number of typical workarounds for usernames are not permitted: `jane.doe`, `JohnDoe` and `Björk_Guðmundsdóttir` would all be invalid.

What could I call this field so that it still feels like the user's identity, without disappointing them (too much) when they realise the restrictions?

(I thought of having a [separate "full name" or "what shall we call you" field](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names) but I can't guarantee that I'll use that functionality.)

Comment: Your design would really piss me off as a user. And if you want to send me emails, ask me for me email address and accept if I tell you you can't have it.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why you shouldn't call it *Username*. Because that's what it is, and that's what the users will expect to see.

However, it's important that you make the user aware of the limitations. Helper text in the style of the [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout) is proven to work well.

[image: Material Design Helper Text for constrained username]

An of course, validate the users input and let them know if they've entered something wrong after they've de-selected the username field.

Detailed information on validation can be found in this [Designmodo article](https://designmodo.com/ux-form-validation/).

Comment: This makes the most sense. Concern about how users will feel about the restrictions could be catered for by providing an icon or text link (near the restriction information) that invokes a tooltip. "Why all the restrictions?" "Your username will be used for multiple purposes e.g. email prefix, .....,  ......., and needs to be as compatible as possible."

Comment: thanks also for the screenshot, this expression of the restrictions is really clear and unambiguous